# Reading Max value from the XML file VIA SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My data is stored in a table `Transactiontable`. I have columns in the table, one of which is `PostIT` that stores XML data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX21S.png)---TABLE IMAGE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4kqz.png)---XML IMAGE

From the xml file I have to read the max or the most recent transaction datetime.

I am able to read the first node

```
select 
    convert(xml.Transactiontable).value ('Transaction/DateTime[2]','DATETIME') 
from 
    dbo.transactiontable;
```

I have to read all the transactional datetime and I should be able to select the max or the latest transaction

I tried cross apply and did not work

```
select 
    T.N.value ('Transaction/DateTime[2]','DATETIME') 
from
    dbo.transactiontable
cross apply 
    XXX.nodes('TRANSACTION') as T(N)
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Also please show the **sample XML** you're referring to in your code snippets here.

Comment: XML and Table structure posted as image

Comment: That's another thing that doesn't go down well with most here, because it makes creating a test fiddle a lot harder. Can you repost as text? Or better, create a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk) ?

Comment: I am assuming that your DB is MS SQL Server. Please add a T-SQL script for DDL and sample data population to your question. We also need a desired output based on the data sample from you. An image is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to say first:

- Please do not paste your sample data as picture. Nobody wants to type this in.
- Best was, to provide a MCVE or a fiddle with DDL, sample data and your own attempt together with the expected output.
- Always tag as specifically as possible. Tag with your tools and provide vendor and version.

Now to your question:

Again there is something to say first:

- Your XML contains date-time values in a culture dependant format. This is dangerous. some systems will take "01/05/2019" as the first of May, others will read the 5th of January.
- The XML is hard to read. If I get the picture correctly, you have alternating `<Datetime>` and `<TRANSACTION_KEY>` elements. It seems to be their sort order to tigh them together. This is a bad design...

Try this as first step:

```
SELECT dt.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS SomeDateTimeValueAsString
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.TheXmlColumn.nodes('/DATA/CO/TRANSACTION/DateTime') A(dt);
```

If this is not enough to get you running, you'll have to invest more effort to your question.